# Windows 10 wsl2 unbuntu 20.04 python cv2 cannot see watec 933 camera

Tags: python, windows, opencv, tkinter, wsl-2

I am trying to run a video feed into a tkinter canvas widget by using cv2.  I am using Windows 10, version 21H2, OS build 19044.1348.(I am not allowed to upgrade due to where I work.)  I am using wsl2 and running Ubuntu 20.04.  I am using a Watec 933 video camera.  As a diagnostic I am able to see the video by using VLC's video streaming function.

When I look at /dev I do not see any video mounts at all.

When I run my python code, which is just the following set of commands :

```
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2)
(ref, frame) = cap.read()
```

I get the following error:

```
global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (889) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

My question is:  Does anyone know how to diagnose this error?

Clearly ubuntu is not showing any devices but at the same time I am able to see the video using VLC. I am confused about the interplay between windows and ubuntu.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  I have looked on the web but to no avail.

Comment: is VLC installed in the VM? or do you run the host's VLC?

Comment: VLC is installed on the host machine.  Still not sure how windows 10 interacts with Ubuntu.

Comment: if VLC is installed in the host OS, it will run in a host context. it won't even know there is a linux. using this VLC proved nothing. -- have you researched whether accessing a webcam is even possible from inside of WSL2?

Comment: I have not tried to determine if I can run VLC on Ubuntu.  Actually I am not really interested in VLC but rather tkinter.  The whole issue of the intereplay between Windows 10 and WSL-2 is good for me to understand but for now I have been able to get my video camera to be seen by cv2 and that is what I was looking for help with.  If you know of any books or instructions on how Windows and WSL-2 work together I would be grateful to know.  For instance, I had a difficult time getting Ubuntu to display correctly.  I was hoping that I could just use WSL-2 to access my linux work without problems.

Comment: if there is no requirement to use wsl/wsl2/any virtualization, then _don't_ use it. it's added complication.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  I had to change:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

to :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.1.250:554/h264')
```

I found a variation of this solution on stack overflow.